# AWS Api Gateway - Java SDK generation "Internal error occurred while generating SDK"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I can successfully generate Android and javascript SDKs from Api Gateway, but I can't for Java.  I get a message saying "Internal error occurred while generating SDK".

How can I figure out what's causing this?

*Other's have pointed out model descriptions causing the issue...  I've removed all of them and it still doesn't work.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android and Javascript autogenerated SDK's are much more lenient than Javas.  Java's is extremely picky--it didn't like one of my models basically.

I have no documentation for this--I learned it by creating a new api gateway endpoint and incrementally adding models to it and downloading the autogenerated sdk until I figured out which model was causing the problem.  Not fun.